# Adding text to label from variable

Tags: powershell, label

Take this code, the function is using vsphere cmd-let to retrieve CPU number based on a selected VM from a list box. The output was working into another list box but I want to be able to output the result to a label

```
function fill_updatelistbox 
{
$vmlist1 = Get-vm -Name $listBox1.SelectedItem | select NumCPU
foreach ($vm1 in $vmlist1)
{
$label1.Text($vm1.NumCPU)
}
}


$label1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 400
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 115
$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Name = "label1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$label1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label1.TabIndex = 0
$label1.Text = ""
```

Edited: The below code worked using a listbox

```
function fill_updatelistbox
{
$vmlist1 = Get-vm -Name $listBox1.SelectedItem | select NumCPU
foreach ($vm1 in $vmlist1)
{
[void]$listBox2.Items.Add($vm1.NumCPU)
}
}

$tabPage2.Controls.Add($panel2)
$listBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$listBox2.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 1
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 1
$listBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$listBox2.Name = "listBox2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 369
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 160
$listBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$listBox2.TabIndex = 0
$panel2.Controls.Add
```

Comment: missing lots of info here. ex. is multi-selection allowed in listbox? because atm. each vm that get-vm returns will overwrite the last vms cpu in the label.

Comment: hi Graimer, I don't require multi-selection. I will have several labels that display different data like memory stats, datastore location, RAM etc.

Comment: I submitted an untested suggestion, but I must admit that this is 100% untested. If it doesn't work, can you be more specific about what doesn't work? You say it worked when you displayed it in a listbox, can you provide the `fill_updatelistbox` code you used then? Does it display anything or just blank? It's pretty unclear atm.

Comment: theres another function that retrieves the vm names and pumps them to a listbox. When a server name is clicked on, information about that particular server is shown, i.e. by the use of labels. I got the expected result by outputting to a listbox before ok

Comment: can you provide the listbox code? just to see what used to work to get the numCPU value.

Comment: just edited question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I don't have the resources to test this, but I'll try to help. First, make sure the listbox is single-choice, because label is more of a single-item textbox :) Then you can try:

```
function fill_updatelistbox 
{
#Should return a single VirtualMachine object
$vm = Get-vm -Name ($listBox1.SelectedItem.toString())
$label1.Text = $vm.NumCPU.toString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tired it and recieved the error;  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Olly\Desktop\tail.ps1:178 char:34
+ $label1.Text($vm1.NumCPU.toString <<<< ())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (toString:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: 'Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Forms.Label] doesn't contain a method named 
'Text'.
At C:\Users\Olly\Desktop\tail.ps1:178 char:13
+ $label1.Text <<<< ($vm.NumCPU.toString())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Text:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound'

Comment: sry. another embarrassing typo, should be the last one. :P Text is a property(string) not a method. if it doesn't work now I have no idea.